# error: <identifier> expected with addActionListener class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm having issues with this simple block of Java code. I'm supposed to write an application that displays a JFrame containing the opening sentence from A Christmas Carol. When the user clicks the button, it will display the title of the book that contains the quote in the available JLabel using the setText() method.

However, when I compile, I'm getting errors that an  is expected for my line to add the ActionListener for the button. I feel like I'm missing something simple, but I can't place it. Below is my source code. Thanks for any help.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class JBookQuote extends JFrame{
   FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout();
   JLabel msg1 = new  JLabel("To begin with,");
   JLabel msg2 = new JLabel("Marley was dead.");
   JButton button = new JButton("Click for source");
   JLabel msg3 = new JLabel();
   String title = "**    A Christmas Carol    **";
    public JBookQuote() {
        add(msg1);
        add(msg2);
        add(button);
        add(msg3);
        setLayout(flow);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {     
          msg3.setText(title);
    }
});
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JBookQuote aFrame = new JBookQuote();
        aFrame.setSize(300, 150);
        aFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: `button.addActionListener` can't be executed outside of a executable block, like a constructor or method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code to add the actionlistener to your button isn't in a function, I think you want it in your constructor.